# Como restrintir o formato da coleção com regras no Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-database

Ao cadastrar um usuário, tenho que enviar este json para o endpoint:

```
{
  "email": "joao123@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "João",
  "lastName": "Silva",
  "password": "*********",
  "birthday": "2000-01-01"
}
```

Todavia, tenho que realizar as validações; para isso, estou utilizando as seguintes regras:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
      "$uid": {
        ".validate": "
            newData.hasChildren(['firstName', 'lastName', 'birthday', 'email', 'password']) &&
            newData.child('birthday').val().matches(/^(19|20)[0-9]{2}\\-(0[1-9]|1[1-2])\\-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30)$/i)
        "
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Agora, o problema é: Se eu tentar enviar um json com uma quantidade de chaves menor que aquelas específicadas pela regras, não será possível. Contudo, se eu enviar um json contendo as chaves específicadas pelas regras e, outras chaves adicionais, então, ele irá adicionar sem problemas.

Exemplo:

### ERRO

```
{
  "email": "joao123@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "João",
  "lastName": "Silva",
  "password": "*********"
}
```

### SUCESSO

```
{
    "email": "joao123@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "João",
    "lastName": "Silva",
    "password": "*********",
    "birthday": "2000-01-01",
    "nao_previsto": "valor"
 }
```

Existe alguma maneira de validar este json de tal maneira que: SOMENTE seja inserido no banco de dados se o json enviado no request siga EXATAMENTE o formato (SEM INSERIR chaves não previstas)?